# How to remove an element from jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

Code:

```
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    var j=$();
    j=j.add("#d1");
    j=j.add("#d2");

    j.remove("#d1");//not this...
    //alert(j.length);
    j.css("border","1px solid red");
});
</script>
```

I've used `j.add()` to add elements to `j`, but how do I remove `#d1` from `j`?

`j.remove()` is not working, because it removes the `#d1` and `j.length` still be 2.

Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
<script>
$(function(){
 var j=$();
 j=j.add("#d1");
 j=j.add("#d2");

 j=j.not("#d1");
 //alert(j.length);
 j.css("border","1px solid red");
});
</script>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ew9Z5/)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
```

```js
$(function(){
    var j=$("#d1, #d2");
    j.filter(":not( #d1 )").css("border","1px solid red");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the manipulation methods (e.g. `add()`) does not manipulate the object (collection) *in-place* but *returns* an altered collection. Thus, you need to assign the return value from <del>`remove()`</del> `not()` back to `j`:

```
j.remove("#d1");//not this...
```

Should be

```
j = j.not("#d1");//not this...
```

---

**`remove()` vs. `not()`**

[`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the matched set from the DOM (not the set), while [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) removes the matched set from the given match leaving the DOM unaltered. I think you're looking for `not()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery [grep()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) function:

```
<div id="d1">d1</div>
<div id="d2">d2</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    var j=$();
    j=j.add("#d1");
    j=j.add("#d2");

    j = jQuery.grep(arr, function(item){
        return item != '#d1';
    });
    j.css("border","1px solid red");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why? It seems a little complex :)

Comment: For expandability of course, in case the filter ever needs to be more complex. But I do agree, for this particular case the chosen answer does the trick just fine.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
j.find("#d1").remove();
```

if not:

```
j.filter("#d1").remove();
```